# iOS the quality of drawing lines using CGContext is much worse than SKShapeNode in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, sprite-kit, cgcontext

I'm making a game where the user can draw lines with finger. There are tons of methods on websites. I tried two methods, one using CGContext in UIView (UIKit), and the other using CGPath and SKShapeNode in SpriteKit. But the latter shows much better quality. The first one using CGContext has ugly rough edges.

Please see following screen shots. I also attached part of code for both methods here, (in the `touchesMove` function).

Note: `var ref = CGPathCreateMutable()`

**CGContext in UIView**
[image]

```
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(ref, nil, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    tempImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))


    CGContextAddPath(context, ref)

    // 3
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushWidth)
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, 1.0)
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)

    // 4
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    // 5
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

**SKShapeNode in SpriteKit**
[image]
Note: `var lineDrawing = SKShapeNode()`

```
CGPathAddLineToPoint(ref, nil, location.x, location.y)
lineDrawing.path = ref
lineDrawing.lineWidth = 3
lineDrawing.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor()
lineDrawing.alpha = 1.0
self.addChild(lineDrawing)
```

**How can I draw lines in UIView with the same quality of SKShapeNode?**

Comment: Have a print of the actual paths.  My guess is that there are a different number of paths in each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you're using an outdated function that doesn't handle Retina screens:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
```

You should be using this instead:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, false, 0)
```

The `WithOptions` version, with 0 as the final argument, creates an image context at Retina resolution if the device has a Retina screen. (The 0 argument means “use the device screen's scale factor”.)

There may be other issues, because you didn't show the code that creates the points in the path for each test case.

Comment: It's better, but still not as good as SKShapeNode.  The code for creating path is shown there, as: (1)`var ref = CGPathCreateMutable()`; (2)in touchesBegan, `CGPathMoveToPoint(ref, nil, location.x, location.y)`; (3) in touchesMove, `CGPathAddLineToPoint(ref, nil, location.x, location.y)`. Did I miss anything?

Comment: where the location is `let location = touch.locationInView(self)`

Comment: Try drawing the same shape (with your finger or whatever) at the same speed under both tests. How many points does the path end up with in the `CGContext` implementation? How many in the SpriteKit version?

Comment: Don't know why I had this set at 1.0.  Just improved my own game  A LOT.

Comment: @robmayoff I think you're right. I have multiple `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` lines where I do screen shots and convert to images and analyze pixels information. Only change one line doesn't work, but it works when I change all of them. However, double the pixels drains my CPU because I'm doing heavy pixels editing. So I finally have to stick to the outdated function and add `self.layer.shouldRasterize = true` to make it better, though not as good as retina function.

Comment: @robmayoff But I still don't understand why drawing lines in retina/non-retina function causes so much difference in CPU. For example, the game itself cost ~15% CPU, when I add lines using the first function, the change of CPU is negligible, but when use the 2nd function for retina, the CPU goes up to 60%, even there is only one retina line on the screen. Do you have any suggestion for me? I can put more code here if it's helpful.

Comment: @DanielKanaan set to 1.0 and 0 give me the same result. But retina function cost much more CPU than non-retina function, I don't know why. I only draw lines and screen shot them as image then present in the UIImageView.